# Problem with moving pages in explorer view from SP 2007 to 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, explorer-view, content-migration

So I am working on moving some pages over from an old SharePoint 2007 site to a new 2010 site using explorer view but I am facing some issues.

The pages get moved over no problem, but once they are in 2010 when I try to move/copy them again or change the page template to a different one it gives me an error. This only happens with the pages I moved over from 2007 using explorer view.

Is there any workaround for this or a way to make the pages compatible with 2010 before I move them over?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: This is the error I get An unexpected error has occurred. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: b38c3b9a-2a31-4755-bd7f-e3dae9415545